# Can I use a property sheet to generate project configurations?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to avoid hard coding settings into my .vcxproj files. I'd like to edit a single file, i.e. inherited property sheets (.props),  to change my settings. This works great for compiler and linker settings.  I also use this technique for all my dependent libraries like boost, zlib, for appending the include path and the libpath.

**I'd like to take this a step farther and *create the list of configurations* in one property sheet**. 
 Is this possible. I keep getting a error.

> proj1.vcxproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="configurations.props"/> 

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{36327322-B9FA-4D71-1111-E94F5BB55D57}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>Proj1</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
</Project>
```

> configurations.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="DebugUnicode|Win32">
      <Configuration>DebugUnicode</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
 </Project>
```

> proj1.vcxproj : error  :  Project "proj1" does not contain any
>   configuration.  The project cannot be loaded.

So is this possible?

Comment: Check this out for a possible workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755704/259543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that is a bug I reported in VS 2010 Beta 2, but a fix didn't make RTM.

[Link to Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514008/vcxproj-doesnt-examine-imports-to-find-project-configurations-beta-2)

Comment: I can't view the Connect Bug Report. Is accepted as a bug or 'as designed'

Comment: Just switched the bug to be public.  It still has the status "Active/Bug"

Comment: This is bad news... I hope it's fixed in VS 2011

Comment: @Brian: Check this out for a possible workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755704/259543